# JSON data in HTML page in a table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I struggling print all my data from DB to webpage using JSON.
But I not understand logical how it should work. 
My JSON script:

```
<script> 
$("document").ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("test1.php", function(data) {

        $("#div-my-table").text("<table>");

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            $("#div-my-table").append("<tr><td>" + item.code +"</td><td>" + item.name + "</td></tr>");
        });

        $("#div-my-table").append("</table>");

    });
});     
</script>
```

And test1.php file

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';

$sql = $conn -> prepare("SELECT * FROM DB_NAME");

$sql -> execute();

  while ($row = $sql -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
  {
      $values = array('code'=>$row['code'],
                    'line'=>$row['line']);                  
}
echo json_encode($values);
?>
```

and part of HTML:

```
<body>

<table id="div-my-table">
</table>

</body>
```

And system return back only:

```
<table>
undefined undefined 
undefined undefined
```

Comment: remove the line   $("#div-my-table").text("<table>"); and   $("#div-my-table").append("<table>");

Comment: change `$("document")` to `$(document)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're expecting multiple rows, you need to gather the results properly. The `$values` gets overwritten every iteration.

```
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // add another dimension
    $values[] = array(
        'code'=>$row['code'],
        'line'=>$row['line']
    );                  
}

echo json_encode($values);
```

Or for just one line:

```
echo json_encode($sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

So that they are properly nested.

Then on your JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON("test1.php", function(data) {

        var table_rows = '';

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            table_rows += "<tr><td>" + item.code +"</td><td>" + item.name + "</td></tr>");
        });

        $("#div-my-table").html(table_rows);

    });

});     
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

First make below correction in your code

```
$values[] = array('code'=>$row['code'],'line'=>$row['line']);
```

Above change will append all database value to $value variable and will show all records instead of last record of db

Also Please check with your table name in below query

```
$sql = $conn -> prepare("SELECT * FROM DB_NAME");
```

It seems that you are taking db name constant here instead of table name as mentioned below.

$sql = $conn -> prepare("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME");

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the same `$values` variable each time through the loop. At the end, it will just contain a single row, not an array of all the rows. You need to add each row to `$values`, not replace it. It should be:

```
$values = array();
while ($row = $sql -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
    $values[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($values);
```

Also, your jQuery is wrong. You shouldn't use `.text()` when you're creating HTML, you should use `.html()`. And you don't need to append `</table>` -- these functions operate on the DOM, not the HTML, and the DOM always has complete elements.

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("test1.php", function(data) {

        var table = $("<table>");
        $("#div-my-table").empty().append(table);

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            table.append("<tr><td>" + item.code +"</td><td>" + item.name + "</td></tr>");
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `last.after();`

Instead of `append();`